# Store and retrieve a MySQL Select query using array(BASH)

Tags: mysql, bash

I am trying to store and retrieve the value of MySQL select query through an array. Below is the table values.

```
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
| id        | name          | Qen  | God                 Fat                        
+---------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
|    37     | must1         | MR   | AS                 | DISC |              
|    36     | must2         | MR   | AS                 | DISCR |
|    37     | must3         | MR   | AS                 | DISC |              
|    37     | must4         | MR   | AS                 | DISCR |              
|    37     | must5         | MR   | AS                 | DISC |              
|    36     | must5         | PH   | Int                | DISC |              
|    35     | nust6         | PH   | Int                | DISCR |
```

I am using the below query using shell scripting to get the above mentioned table to display O/P in a table format. If not table just the correct rows and columns. . But I am getting all the values in a single line. Can someone help me figure out how I can get it in a tabular format.

```
qer=($(mysql -uroot -pxxxx -e "select id, name, Qen, God, Fat from db.testtable;"))

   for j in "${qer[@]}";do
    echo -e "$j"
done
```

I am currently printing the output directly to console. But need it in a array so that it can be displayed in different ways.

Comment: if your example data is also your required output, you should edit your question to indicate that. In any case, showing your required output is almost always a good idea. Use the `{}` tool at the top left of the edit box once you have highlighted your data. This will format it as above. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sentence in order to have the interactive output format in batch mode :

```
mysql -u root -p xxx -e "select id, name, Qen, God, Fat from db.testtable;" -t mysql >test.txt
```

And If you wish to have also the command used in the output file you can use :

```
mysql -u root -p xxx -e "select id, name, Qen, God, Fat from db.testtable;" -t -vvv mysql >test2.txt
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need  to know if we can have the information put into an array and then retrieve it in a tabular format.

Comment: Can you provide an example.I don't understand what you really need